# Disable automatic registry update

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, networking, registry

I'm currently trying to change some few things on my work computer (as a challenge) and after few search, came into this matter.
I try to edit a registry that will finally give me freedom (AutoConfigURL of internet explorer).
When I edit it or delete it, it comes back after a short while (matter of seconds).
Which leads me to the conclusion that there is a script somewhere that recreates the registry automatically.
Maybe PowerShell or just a .bat file.
My question being: what are your ideas of finding out where is that script and how to disable it?
Thanks to you all!

Comment: UPDATE : The registry is edited when I try to disable the automatic proxy from internet explorer option.
So I guess it is a script that is executed when this action is performed

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to see what's changing the key. It's an advanced monitoring tool for Windows that shows real-time file system, Registry and process/thread activity. That might can help you to find out the program which changes the registry key.

You could also try the solution in [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/584329/how-can-i-keep-a-windows-registry-key-constant/584335#584335). Try to [set permissions for registry keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2003/cc728310(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN). Immediatly remove all the permissions after you edit the registry key, then it will be read only.